# Running git filter-branch subdirectory-filter to also remove get rid of other subdirectories history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

We have a large repository that has subfolders of `platforms`,

```
sdk/
    .git/
    android/
    ios/
    unity/
    windows/
```

Which we now want to break into their own repositories.  Keeping all the history, and branches of there.

I've run the command

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter android -- --all
```

Which looked like it had run exactly what I'd wanted, promoting the subfolder `android` to be the root of this new repository, and I went to push this to a new remote origin (on GitHub).

When doing this, I got an error message saying there was a file too large to be pushed to remote, but the path of this file was

```
 unity/QAApp/...
```

Which exists in history of the other subfolders that I didn't think `filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` would take.

I'm looking into running a manual

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter \
'git rm -rf --ignore-unmatch ios unity windows && rm -rf ios unity windows' \
-- --all
```

But it seems like this is double-jobbing what I understand `filter-branch subdirectory-filter` should be doing.  Is this expected behaviour, or am I running one or other of the commands incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of back and forward with the git mailing list guys, it does seem like this is a problem with filter-branch.  The main problem here is that filter-branch only interacts with branches that interacted with the subdirectory you're specifying.  If you have some branches which never did, the command won't go near them, leaving you with history in your repo that you may not want.

First way to get what I want is clear out all branches that don't interact with the subdirectory, in this case `android`,

```
path=android/
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' |
while read ref; do
  if test "$(git rev-list --count "$ref" -- "$path")" = 0; then
    echo "delete $ref"
  fi
done | git update-ref --stdin
```

This snippet runs through every branch reference your git repo has, checks to see if it has a reference to your subdirectory, and if it doesn't, delete it.

Next change the filter-branch command,

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat --subdirectory-filter android -- --all
```

Adding `--tag-name-filter cat` to the command redoes the tags and stops a tagged branch from keeping hold of unwanted history.

Last thing to do is then wiping kept backed up history,

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

The filter branch stores a backup of every branch it interacts with.  This is correct and proper behaviour, but for this purpose, when you want to rewrite all history and understand the consequences of what you're doing, then removing the the backup is correct and fine to do.

After all this, you get a properly redone repo, with only the history from within that subdirectory in it, everything else is discarded, including branches that never interacted with that subdirectory.